# Kotlin Long to Float difference

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to convert Long value to Float in Kotlin. However I am seeing it is changing the value by a small fraction.
Here's a simple test run:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val l = 1513741500
    val f:Float = l.toFloat()
    val df = DecimalFormat("0")
    println(df.format(f))
}

Output:
1513741440
```

As can be seen there is a slight difference between the values. How can I ensure the same value is returned on conversion?

Comment: You don't need to go through the dance. `println(1513741500f)` prints the same value. That's not specific to Kotlin. Paste it here and see exactly what happens: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 0):

```
l: Int = 1513741500
f: Float = 1.51374144E9
d: Double = 1.5137415E9
```

So if you plan to use large numbers, rather use Double than Float.

Comment: Yeah I understand it will work with double. But I am using a library which limits me to using Float only.

Comment: @Manish, Perhaps there's a way to scale down the values you give to the library. If it takes a float and values this large are required, then it might be worth contacting the library author(s) about it.

Comment: @Chris, Agreed.. There is bound to be a loss of precision when fitting 64 bits into 32 - no way I can get around that. Your suggestion does make sense and I will go that way - scaling them down. Additionally I will also need to  keep a reference to the original value (these are actually timestamps and will need to be converted back to the Date ). Will also have to figure out how to use this solution with the library now. Thanks mate !

Comment: @Manish why not just use the original int/long timestamp instead of floating it?

Comment: @Pnemonic - I am using a 3rd party library (MPAndroidChart) which expects values in Floats.. My service returns the values in Long. The issue has been raised with library author by other devs already.